# Passing JSON to a Controller with Multiple Models and/or Parameters via AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote this Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckOut(List<POS_model> pos, double totalPayment)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pos);
            DataTable posTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
            posTable.Columns["discount_percent"].ColumnName = @"Discount %";

            POS m_pos = new POS();
            m_pos.Data = posTable;
            m_pos.totalPayment = totalPayment;
            m_pos.CheckOut();

            return Json(new
            {
                Status = "Success"
            });
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Status = "Fail"
            });
        }
    }
```

And i attempted wrote this AJAX script to call and submit the parameters to the Controller:(but it didn't work)

```
var totalPay = 1000;
var GatherPosItems = $('#tblPOS').tableToJSON();

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(GatherPosItems)+"&totalPayment="+totalPay,
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckOut", "POS")',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.toString());
        }
        });
```

The `GatherPosItems` is a JSON with multiple "Rows" or Objects, so it's an array.

I added a parameter `totalPayment`.

How can i pass Both `GatherPosItems` and `totalPayment` to the Controller?

my Model:

```
public class POS_model
{
        public string Qty { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string discount_percent { get; set; }
        public string Discount_amount { get; set; }
        public string Discounted_price { get; set; }
        public string Line_total { get; set; }
        public string is_vat { get; set; }
        public string track_type { get; set; }
        public string item_line_id { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string sale_code { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string unit_of_measure { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string item_code { get; set; }
}
```

My `GatherPosItems`'s RESULT:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558870/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-input-parameters-are-null

Comment: my parameter is Class Model and a normal parameter....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You concatenate a non-JSON string (`&totalPayment="+totalPay`) to the JSON returned from `JSON.stringify` function, which corrupts the format of data being sent to the server and makes the model binder unable to parse it.

The following should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({pos: GatherPosItems, totalPayment: totalPay}),
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckOut", "POS")',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(req, status, errorObj) {
        alert(errorObj.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok.. it's almost working now. But the `pos` now became null in my Controller... Can you help? it's almost working

Comment: @BienvenidoOmosura How your `POS_model` class and `GatherPosItems` object look like ?

Comment: i made some edit so that you can see the Model and for the `GatherPosItems ` , i added some picture

Comment: @BienvenidoOmosura As a side question, why your model class is partial? what's in the other part(s)?

Comment: :aahhmmm.. this is embarassing but your code really did actually works... it was just my typing error.... I'm really very sorry about that... THANK yOU for helping