# Asp.Net Mvc POST method doesn't send string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax doesn't send any strings to the controller.

Here's my function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAnswer').click(function () {
        var code = $('#Answer').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckAnswer", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: code ,
            datatype: "text",

            success: function (resultFromFunct) {
                $("#resultsBox").append(resultFromFunct);
            }

        });
        $('#Answer').val('');
    });
});
```

Here's my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string CheckAnswer(string answer)/
{
    game.LogUserAnswer(Request.Cookies["user"].Value, answer);           
    return String.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>: {1} <br>", Request.Cookies["user"].Value, game.UserGuess(answer));
}
```

Ajax is correctly get into CheckAnswer method but answer is always null. I've tried other examples from stack, for instance [Asp.Net Mvc JQuery ajax input parameters are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558870/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-input-parameters-are-null) but always get null result. Do you have any thoughts of the cause?

Comment: Change `data: code ,` to `data: { answer: code },`

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. Such a dumb mistake. Don't know how to vote for your comment.

Comment: Yodacheese has added an answer so you can accept that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your request parameters to `data: { answer: code }` in your request. It probably can not match `code` to the parameter on your action.

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAnswer').click(function () {
        var code = $('#Answer').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckAnswer", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { answer: code },
            datatype: "text",

            success: function (resultFromFunct) {
                $("#resultsBox").append(resultFromFunct);
            }

        });
        $('#Answer').val('');
    });
});
```